# PyCharm 4.5.3 Django manage.py task not working after update

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, pycharm

After upgrading 4.5.3 my Tools->Run manage.py task no longer works.  Clicking on the link does nothing.  No window pops up.  Going to "Python Console" does not work, same thing, nothing happens.

Going to Django in "Languages and Frameworks" and deselecting django allows the "python console" to properly work as a python interpreter.  Reselecting Django reproduces the above results.

Settings for Django:
Django Project Root is the same folder which contains manage.py
Settings is my settings file
Manage script is manage.py

Settings for Django Console:
proper python interpreter 
working directory is the same directory where manage.py is.

Project runs fine

Again, it all worked fine, updated to 4.5.3, and it stopped working.  Any ideas?

Other issues, caused by the same thing, is that my test configuration doesn't run.

Edit: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16434 - Added

Edit: It's a bug, being fixed

Comment: If there's a bug in PyCharm, report it to JetBrains.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16434  - Thanks.  I'm sure a patch won't come out soon if it truly is a bug (Normally it's a mistake I made hence I posted here).  If there is a work-around I'll post here.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem since going up 4.5.3 - I'm looking for a work around or rollback.

Comment: Let me know if you find one.  I haven't seen a good way to roll back other than completely reinstalling.  Please add that you have an issue to my tracker ticket posted above.  Also, my PyCharm, when run in full screen mode goes to another window when a pop-up comes up - What OS are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 4.5.3 only.  The issue is with the Django Settings file, in TEMPLATES.  It's a bug with the DIRS of TEMPLATES.  See bug report.  I commented out the TEMPLATES and it worked for me.