# PyCharm Run not working

Tags: django, ide, pycharm

I don't know what is going on, but PyCharm is not responding on "Run" command, neither "Run...", neither Tools/Run manage.py.

[image]

I have set up the Django settings :
[image]

I don't have a clue...

EDIT

The logs are:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jetbrains.django.templateFSLoader.DjangoTemplateFSLoader8.getFolders(DjangoTemplateFSLoader8.java:50)
    at com.jetbrains.django.codeInsight.DjangoSettingsPy$1.compute(DjangoSettingsPy.java:224)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.jetbrains.django.codeInsight.DjangoSettingsPy.a(DjangoSettingsPy.java:208)
    at com.jetbrains.django.codeInsight.DjangoSettingsPy.getInstalledApps(DjangoSettingsPy.java:185)
    at com.jetbrains.django.util.DjangoUtil.a(DjangoUtil.java:356)
    at com.jetbrains.django.util.DjangoUtil.addSettingsModule(DjangoUtil.java:333)
    at com.jetbrains.django.util.DjangoUtil.addPyCharmSettingsModule(DjangoUtil.java:324)
    at com.jetbrains.django.run.DjangoServerRunCommandLineState.<init>(DjangoServerRunCommandLineState.java:63)
    at com.jetbrains.django.run.DjangoServerRunConfiguration.getState(DjangoServerRunConfiguration.java:84)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:201)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:58)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:94)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.a(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:396)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$5.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:332)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

And I found this: [PyCharm 4.5.3 Django manage.py task not working after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361738/pycharm-4-5-3-django-manage-py-task-not-working-after-update)

But I don't want to change my config file juste for a bug in the IDE!

Comment: maybe try with IDLE and see if your program runs there. If it does then, you have an issue with your configuration. If it doesn't, then it is your code.

Comment: It works perfecly with a simple manage.py runserver

Comment: your Environment variables is empty in your configuration, try adding the python path you want to use for your project.

Comment: I never use pycharms run. running this way comes from java world and I hate java, making a small fabfile.py with shorcut functions is super easy and more flexibel

Comment: More Info [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Comment: Check log files (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827517-Locating-IDE-log-files) and report their support

Comment: Not working with a pythonpath as environment variable

Comment: @user996142 logs helped to find this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361738/pycharm-4-5-3-django-manage-py-task-not-working-after-update , but I am not going to edit my settings

Comment: @doniyor interested, can you give me some link or tuto?

Comment: @VincentLê http://www.fabfile.org/